# How do I access the array of posts from a custom taxonomy so I can sort it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy called mwp_ss_supp.  I have a page that displays all the posts using this code:

```
<?php $count = wp_count_posts('mwp_ss_supp')->publish;
    echo '<div id="post-count">' . $count . ' posts displayed</div>';?>
        
<?php       
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    
    DO STUFF


  <?php 
    endwhile; 
endif; ?>
```

The problem is that all the posts are displaying in the order of latest post is the first on the list published.  But I want to print them in a different order (ie, posts 1-10 are published first, posts 15-20 are published next, and 11-14 are published last, which ends up being published in alphabetical order by title). So how do I access this array of posts?  There doesn't seem to be an array variable to play around with.

Comment: You could collect the posts in an array in your "DO STUFF" section. Then sort them in the way you want (e.g. "ascendingly"). Then finally display them how you want (e.g. a big list, pagination, etc)

Comment: This is the one that actuallly worked the best for me.  I went through the `if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();` loop and put the current `$post` into an array, then messed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Show sql query for that.  The sql query gets data from the database and determines the sort

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom wordpress query `WP_Query()` to query posts against taxonomies:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy_type',
    );
  );
'orderby'=> 'title', 
'order' => 'ASC',
);

/**
* WP_Query()
* The WordPress Query class.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
*/
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    if( get_the_title() !== '' ):
      the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
    endif;
    if( get_the_content() !== '' ):
      the_content();
    endif;
  endwhile;
endif;

/**
* wp_reset_postdata()
* After looping through a separate query, this function restores the $post global to the current post in the main query.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/
*/
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- `wp_query` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a pre_get_posts() modifier to your theme's functions.php:

```
function taxo_posts($query)
{
    if ($query->is_tax('mwp_ss_supp') && $query->is_main_query())
    {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' ); // or DESC
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'taxo_posts');
```